# Why 'grep -l' is not matching all files containing a certain string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, find

From time to time I face a very weird behavior with find + grep commands. I am asking this because I haven't found anything related to this.

At my work I often have to perform a considerable search against a high amount of logs, looking for a certain string.

Due to its excellent performance I trust heavily on the command `grep -l` to execute this.

I use commands like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*log*" -exec grep -l STRING {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

I also have a multi-thread program that use `find + grep -l` in a parallel way.

The problem is that sometimes **some files are not found during the search, even though they contain the string I am interested in**. Then, when I execute the same command for a second time, the searching works and show me all the files I am interested in.

This seems to be a very intermittent issue and I have no idea of what I should check.

Any idea of what could cause that? Could it be a problem with `find` that set parameters for `grep` command? Is it a grep problem? May it be related to the high amount of files we search on a certain time.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see a pattern on the files that are _just_ found the second time?

Comment: The answer might lie where you sent standard error to, i.e. in /dev/null.

Comment: I have noticed that the second search is always way faster than the first one. I believe this happens because the files are loaded in cache/virtual memory due to recent use. Maybe they are better processed because they are in memory? I have a good understand of OSes that does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Examples of files found during the second try:

/logfiles/something/logs/CLIENTBRDG/Bridge.log.2018-01-31
/logfiles/something/logs/CLIENTBRDG/INBOUND.log
/logfiles/something/logs/CLIENTBRDG/INBOUND.log.2018-01-31
/logfiles/something/logs/CLIENTBRDG/Bridge.log

Comment: You could use `grep -lr --include='*log*' 'STRING'` or even `grep -Flr --include='*log*' 'STRING'` if `STRING` is a fixed string instead of `find -exec`. If you don't see the problem then, it would point to using `find` being the problem.

Comment: As @choroba pointed out - you're redirecting stderr to /dev/null so if find or grep are telling you what the problem is you're just throwing that info away.

Comment: I see, this command is actually encapsulated inside a Java Program, I may have to think in some logging scheme to capture possibly errors from the command.